# Line appears in OverlayItem on Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm using an ItemizedOverlay on a Google Maps in an Android application.  My extension of ItemizedOverlay is shown below.

The strange thing is I see a small line from about the 8 o'clock position to the 2 o'clock position in every occurrence of the overlay.  The overlay is a png that is in my application resources (which obviously doesn't have the strange line).  I've attached an example of the raw png overlay (R.drawable.green) here: [image: png in my resource directory]

And here is what I see in the android app: [image]

(You kind of have to look closely to see the gray line I'm talking about.  It is under the green dots and under the little airplane icon.)

The overlay is added as follows:

```
ReportOverlay itemizedoverlay = new ReportOverlay(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.green),mContext);
GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(pr.getLat(),pr.getLng());
OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, pr.getReport(),pr.getReport());
itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
```

Any idea where this mystery line in the overlay is coming from?!

```
public class ReportOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

protected ArrayList<OverlayItem> mOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
Context mContext;

public ReportOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
    super(boundCenter(defaultMarker));
}
public ReportOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
    super(boundCenter(defaultMarker));
    mContext = context;
}
public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
    mOverlays.add(overlay);
    populate();
}

@Override
protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
    return mOverlays.get(i);
}

@Override
protected boolean onTap(int index) {
  OverlayItem item = mOverlays.get(index);
  AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
  dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
  dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
  dialog.show();
  return true;
}

@Override
public int size() {
    return mOverlays.size();
}
```

}

Comment: I have to admit I don't really see a grey line as such, but perhaps it's the marker's shadow you're referring to? You can disable it by overriding the ItemizedOverlay's [`draw(...)`](http://code.google.com/intl/en-EN/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/ItemizedOverlay.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas,%20com.google.android.maps.MapView,%20boolean%29) method and call `super.draw(canvas, mapView, false);`. Does that solve your 'problem'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MH suggested, it was indeed the shadow that I was seeing.  Turning it off fixed the issue.